# How can I get fileMatch validation working while editing for local json schemas?

Tags: json, validation, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I've worked through the json schema guidance at [Editing JSON with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json).  In particular, I've tried to reproduce the following behavior described by that document:

> ###### Mapping to a schema in the workspace
>
> To map a schema that is located in the workspace, use a relative path.
> In this example, a file in the workspace root called myschema.json
> will be used as the schema for all files ending with .foo.json.
>
> ```
> "json.schemas": [
>     {
>         "fileMatch": [
>             "/*.foo.json"
>         ],
>         "url": "./myschema.json"
>     }
> ]
> ```

That document doesn't have a complete combination of schema and data files to test against, so I've use the example from [json-schema.org Miscellaneous Examples
Basic](https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html) (with `$id` and `$schema`, which [seem to be unsupported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155379) removed).

### Repro

I'm using version 1.76.0.

Here is the whole workspace:

[image: screenshot of workspace]

#### `.\vscode\settings.json`

```
{
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "folder/*.foo.json"
            ],
            "url": "./myschema.json"
        }
    ]   
}
```

I've experimented with a variety of different patterns for `"fileMatch"` but didn't find a way to affect the behavior.

#### `.\myschema.json`

```
{
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

#### `folder\no_schema_specified.foo.json`

```
{
    "age" : "nine"
}
```

[[image: no_schema_specified]

#### `folder\schema_specified.foo.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "../myschema.json",
    "age" : "nine"
}
```

[[image: schema_specified.foo.json]

### What I was expecting

I was expecting that `"nine"` would produce an error in both.

### What actually happens

`"nine"` only produces the error in the data file where `$schema` is explicitly specified.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the information you have provided. It works for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: There's this issue, but it's not related since it's about multi-root workspaces: [\[json\] schema validation in a folder of a workspace stops working when more folders are added to it #147865](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147865), and already got fixed recently.

Comment: [The repro](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124491#issuecomment-1448413811) for [this open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124491) is very similar.  That problem seems to be particular to Windows.